# Dependency injection for settings class cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

Okay, I'm obviously doing something stupid here but I can't seem to find it.

I'm writing my first Razor Pages app and created an `EmailSender` class, which implements `IEmailSender`. In addition, the `EmailSender` constructor accepts an `EmailSettings` parameter. `EmailSettings` is implemented as follows.

**appsettings.json**

```
"EmailSettings": {
  "Host": "****.*****.com",
  "Port": "587",
  "UserName": "****@**********.com",
  "Password": "***********",
  "FromAddress": "****@**********.com",
  "EnableSsl": "true"
},
```

**EmailSettings.cs**

```
public class EmailSettings
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FromAddress { get; set; }
    public bool EnableSsl { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // ...

    services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
}
```

This follows the basic approach taken from an [article I read](https://kenhaggerty.com/articles/article/aspnet-core-22-smtp-emailsender-implementation). But when I run the app, I get an immediate exception:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Bamtok.Services.EmailSender': Unable to resolve service for type 'Bamtok.Services.EmailSettings' while attempting to activate 'Bamtok.Services.EmailSender'.)'

Somehow, it is not able to instantiate an `EmailSettings` instance to pass to the `EmailSender` constructor.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Configure adds  `IOptions<EmailSettings>` and most likely you injected `EmailSettings` into the dependent class.

Comment: Linked article shows `IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSettings` being injected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Configure<T>` registers `IOptions<EmailSettings>` and, as you stated, you injected `EmailSettings` into the dependent class.

You can either leave the class as is and refactor `Startup`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    // ...

    EmailSettings settings = Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings").Get<EmailSettings>();
    services.AddSingleton(settings);
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
}
```

**Or** update the class to expect the `IOptions<T>` dependency

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender {
    private readonly EmailSettings emailSettings;

    public EmailSender(IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSettings) {
        this.emailSettings = emailSettings.Value;
    }

    //...
}
```

The difference between the former over the latter suggestion is that the implementation will not be coupled to framework concerns.